# Having trouble linking a button

Tags: html, css

I'm only just learning html and have a question about linking a button. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
</style>
<body>
<button onClick="name.html" class="button" ><span>name </span> </button>
<br>
```

Comment: </style>
<body>
<button onClick="maroeska.html" class="button" ><span>Maroeska </span> </button>
<br>

Comment: Why not use an [`a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) tag if you want to redirect to a new page: `<a href="maroeska.html" class="button" ><span>Maroeska </span></a>`

Comment: A [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) is not an [anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) (aka link), it's worth reading the documentation I've linked and understanding the differences.

Answer (score 1):

In your application you should rather use an anchor link, because the button mostly used in forms. The corresponding HTML tag is `<a>`.
If you want to make your link look like a button you can give it a class and design it with CSS.

```
<a href="name.html" class="button">name</a>

   
<style>
    .button {
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          border: none;
          color: white;
          padding: 15px 32px;
          text-align: center;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: inline-block;
          font-size: 16px;
    }
</style>
```